# Create and insert wordpress product tags programatically using wp_set_object_terms

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, metadata

I have around 2000 products which has no tags. Now i want to update tag for those products. I want to set post_title=tag for all 2000 products.

Below code works for a product to set CUSTOM TAG to PRODUCT

```
wp_set_object_terms($productID, array('product_tag1','product_tag2','product_tag3'), 'product_tag');
```

Instead of complicating the work from front end for each product.

Can someone please guide me how to set **post_title=tag** using php for all my products.

Comment: you want to set the post title as a tag?

Comment: @Mason - Yes. I am using woocommerce. I want to set post_title = tag where post_type=product

Comment: @Mason - any guidance or lead to resolve this

Answer (score 1):

You can loop through your products and assign the tags, maybe something like this:

**Update:**
If you want to just add a tag to posts which dont have any existing tags, you could do something like this:

```
<?php
add_action('init', 'add_tags_products');

function add_tags_products()
{
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'products', // your product post type
        'posts_per_page' => - 1,
    );

    $posts = get_posts($args);

    foreach ($posts as $post):
        setup_postdata($post);

        // get the title of the post
        $title = get_the_title($post->ID);

        // check to see if the post has any tags
        if( ! has_term( '', 'product_tag', $post->ID ) ) :
            // create the term
            wp_set_object_terms($post->ID, array($title), 'product_tag');
        endif;

        wp_reset_postdata();
    endforeach;

}
```

Paste the above code in your `index.php` file for testing and visit the site, and after all the tags are set, remove it. Also backup first in case something happens.

Comment: I added it in functions.php but it did nothing

Comment: while the code is working exceptionally good. It has just 1 small problem, it replace the old tags. I want it should set tags only for products that have no tag. I.e product having empty tags

Comment: Just add a condition that checks if post contains tag or not

Comment: Can u please update the code with relevant condition.

Comment: Code does not work after "Empty tag" conditions update

Comment: I tested this code on a dev environment and it works, did you get an error

Comment: i also tested the code on 20 products (test website, same live replica)..it worked...but when i run on actual website of 2100 products, it did nothing

Comment: oh interesting, maybe try to change `posts_per_page` to 500 and see if it runs?

Comment: you probably need to increase the maximum execution time in php

Comment: check your server logs, I am not sure why it would work on live site